# Why did the Ferengi stay there in "The Price" after Geordi's warning?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, ferengi

In "The Price" (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*, episode 308), the Ferengi are keen on buying an apparently stable wormhole.

When they enter the wormhole with Data and La Forge to test its stability they stay on the other side of the wormhole, despite the warning from Geordi about its instability. They did not seem to care about it because they looked like they had another plan.

Why didn't they go back like Geordi suggested?

Comment: They didn't have another plan; they just didn't believe that the wormhole really was unstable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starfleet engineers are known to be *highly* cautious.

> **GILORA:** *What are the chances that both a primary system and its backup would fail at the same time?*
>
> **O'BRIEN:** *It's very unlikely, but in a crunch **I wouldn't like to be caught without a second backup.***
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Destiny](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/461.htm)</sup></sub>

While this might be seen as wise by humans, the Ferengi view this as a truly *deplorable* trait, one that stands in the way of the pursuit of opportunity. Per their Rule of Acquisition #62;

> *The riskier the road, the greater the profit.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Ferengi Rules of Acquisition](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ferengi_Rules_of_Acquisition)</sup></sub>

---

There's also a strong suggestion that their scientist is an incompetent who simply doesn't recognise the danger.

> **ARRIDOR:** *They panic quickly under pressure.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Price - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/156.txt)</sup></sub>

---

Purely as an aside, it would seem that the Ferengi's instincts were (unintentionally) correct. By remaining in the vicinity of the wormhole they were able to find a brand new, uncontacted world which they were then able to take over in [Voy: False Profits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/False_Profits_(episode)).